# Getting a null value?

Tags: java, android

Just working on this project, the getImageList() method is returning null value, after passing the right values in the right places. I also did some logging to verify it.

Please just take a look at it.

Here's code:

```
public class GalleryImage extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<StoryModel> arrayList;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_image);


ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.galleryListView);
Intent intent = getIntent();

String file = intent.getStringExtra("fileName");
String[] files = intent.getStringArrayExtra("filesName");

StoryModel model;

GalleryImage image = new GalleryImage();
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : files) {
    model = new StoryModel();
    String concat = file + "/" + s;
    model.setPath(concat);
    arrayList.add(model);
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: Path " + model.getPath());
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ArrayList " + arrayList.add(model));
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: getImageList: " + image.getImageList());
}

CustomAdapter galleryAdapter = new CustomAdapter(GalleryImage.this, R.layout.whatsapp_gallery_image, image.getImageList(), files);
listView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter);
}

private ArrayList<StoryModel> getImageList() {
return arrayList;
}

}
```

Here's logcat:

```
2020-12-16 23:39:06.082 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: Path /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp Status Downloader/0914b4b418414982960aabe18f718e1d.jpg

2020-12-16 23:39:06.082 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: ArrayList true

2020-12-16 23:39:06.082 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: getImageList: null

2020-12-16 23:39:06.083 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: Path /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp Status Downloader/bf51fb0d3efa4ec89b71b86bfe0534f9.jpg

2020-12-16 23:39:06.083 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: ArrayList true

2020-12-16 23:39:06.083 2628-2628/com.example.whatsappstatusdownloader I/GalleryImage: onCreate: getImageList: null
```

Comment: Seems like your `new GalleryImage()` call is not returning anything, contrary to what you want.

Comment: You create a new `GalleryImage` object and assign it to `image` variable, then do *absolutely nothing* to it, and you're surprised that `image.getImageList()` returns null? --- Since you also have `GalleryImage.this` in your code, and the code presumable compiles ok, we can infer that the code is in the `GalleryImage` class, but `this.arrayList` and `image.arrayList` are two different values, so modifying `arrayList` (aka `this.arrayList` aka `GalleryImage.thisarrayList`) will in no way do anything to `image.arrayList` (aka `image.getImageList()`?)

Comment: @IvanGarza ok I think you misread my problem. I want my getImageList() method to return value. Not the class. And just let me edit the question for you clearly. Thanks for responding though.

Comment: What happens in GalleryImage constructor?

Comment: Why are you creating a `GalleryImage` inside the `onCreate` method of another instance of a `GalleryImage`? You are populating the `arrayList` of the existing `GalleryImage`, but not of the **new** `GalleryImage`, so its `arrayList` field will still be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to arrayList declarations in your code. You have two.
In OnCreate you declare it like that:

```
arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and you populate this list, whereas image.getImageList() returns another instance:

```
private ArrayList<StoryModel> arrayList;
```

Comment: sorry man, but I don't get it. I mean I am setting the value of the ArrayList by adding an object of StoryModel i.e., the class of getter and setter methods. And as I had made it global variable so, that I can access it where even I want and also it does changes the value and hence it would set the value and hoped that it would not return null value, throughout the class. But, in this case it is returning the value. And that's my question that, why is it returning the values as null.

Answer (score 0):

You create image. But you don't add anything. So, completely it will return null